# Bootstrap navbar change height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I don't know why, my navbar isn't centered. My buttons aren't aligned at the center and I want to change the navbar height.

How I could do that? This is the navbar:

[image: navbar]

And this is the code:

```css
.extra-margin {
   margin-bottom: 1%;
}
.extra-padding{
   padding-top: 1%;
}
.extra-button{
   margin-left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
       <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-fixed-top extra-margin">
          <ul>
             <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="{% url 'interface:users' %}">Lista Pacientes</a>
             <a class=" btn btn-outline-success" href="{% url 'interface:users' %}">Añadir Paciente</a>
             <a class=" btn btn-outline-danger" href="{% url 'interface:users' %}">Eliminar Paciente</a>
          </ul>
    
          <form class="navbar-form navbar navbar-right extra-padding" action="{% url 'interface:users' %}" method="post">
             {% csrf_token %}
             <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" name="search_text" class="form-control" placeholder="ID del Paciente">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                   <button class="btn btn-outline-warning extra-button" type="submit">  Buscar Paciente
                   </button>
                </div>
             </div>
          </form>
       </nav>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put the buttons inline use the following style change:

```
nav ul
{
  margin: 0;
}
```

In default, the `ul` has some bottom margin.

https://www.bootply.com/ruS4ad9IoW

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this in your CSS using the `@navbar-height`.
When you create the navbar have a minimum of 50px.
Now about vertical centered you can use `vertical-align: middle;` and change the margin to 0 in the ul element, normally ul have a margin